# Qt Translation lupdate and namespaces

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization

While developing a Qt Application, I ran into a problem in using QTranslator. After a little research, I found out that the problem was with lupdate from Qt having problem with the

```
using namespace;
```

directive. Following the instructions found in [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/linguist-programmers.html), I discovered that I have to use special comments in my code, to help lupdate understand that the classes are inside a namespace. The special comment is something like this:

```
 /*
 TRANSLATOR namespace::MyClass
 */
```

So, I added this comments in all my sources that had QStrings being managed by tr. But, still, the applications is not being translated. The installTranslator method of QTranslator is returning true. The actual code I'm using to install the Translator is

```
Application app(argc,argv); //Application is a subclass of QApplication
QTextCoded::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));
QTranslator translator;
translator.load(QString("..//language//") + locale);
app.installTranslator(&translator);
app.exec();
```

Have anyone ran into the same problem? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT--

Corrected one little mistake in the code above, but still no results.

Comment: Blind guess: Are you using QObject::tr() on strings that you want translated? Also, Qt cannot know about dynamic strings while lupdate'ing, therefore if you know what strings will appear (maybe retrieved from a DB) you have to make sure that they appear inside tr() even if that code never executes.

Comment: @erelender Yes, I'm using tr() in all compile time strings I have (Labels and Buttons text, in major). And yet, I'm not getting the translation right.

Answer (score 0):

You do install the translator but do not load any translation for it.

The documentation you link to specifies exactly:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QTranslator translator;
     translator.load(QString("arrowpad_") + locale); // here load translation
     app.installTranslator(&translator);

     app.exec()
}
```

Comment: Ops... I forgot this step, but that is not the problem (I've tryed it before). I'm editing the question.